# Display Value from foreign key in gridview using BLL,DAL

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

I have 3 tables : Car_Model, Car_Brand and Car_Type

Car_Model has 2 foreign keys to the 2 other tables.
I want to display everything of car_model in a gridview with instead of the foreignkeys of the 2 other tables, their values.

Currently i have the following function in my DAL:

```
Private dc As New ModelDataContext

    Public Function selectAll() As List(Of Model)

        Dim result = From p In dc.Models
                     Join a In dc.Brands
                     On p.car_brand Equals a.Car_Brand_Id
                     Join t In dc.Types
                     On p.Car_type Equals t.Car_Type_id
                     Select p

        Return result.ToList
    End Function
```

And the following in my BLL:

```
Public Function selectAll() As List(Of Model)

    Return DALm.selectAll

End Function
```

Comment: A gridview with the following: Car_model_id || Car_model_desrc || Doors || ... || Car_Brand (fk id value) || Car_Type (fk id value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally relations can be mapped like this:

```
Class Model
    Public Property Brand As Car_Brand
    Public Property Type As Car_Type
    ...
End Class
```

But if you want to fetch them yourself you can create an intermediate class that looks like that:

```
Class Car_ViewModel
    Public Property Car As Model
    Public Property Brand As Car_Brand
    Public Property Type As Car_Type
End Class
```

And then in your query:

```
Public Function selectAll() As List(Of Car_ViewModel)

    Dim result = From p In dc.Models
                 Join a In dc.Brands
                 On p.car_brand Equals a.Car_Brand_Id
                 Join t In dc.Types
                 On p.Car_type Equals t.Car_Type_id
                 Select New Car_ViewModel With { .Car = p, .Brand = a, .Type = t }

    Return result.ToList
End Function
```